# Area 51 proposal: Mathematics golf

Tags: discussion, area51

I recently (i.e. yesterday) put a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97391/mathematics-golf) for a 'Mathematics golf' stack exchange on area 51. This would follow the same concept as 'code golf' for which there is already a stack exchange for: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. Please let me know your thoughts / support it if you think it is any good.

**EDIT-in response to  Jyrki Lahtonen's comment**

Here is a quick summary of the concept of code golf:

> 1. A problem/challenge is set in the question, to be solved using a computer program (e.g.: find all the prime numbers under 10,000).
> 2. The answers given contain peoples attempts to solve this problem.
> 3. The answers are scored based on the number of bytes they contain.
> 4. The answer with the lowest number of bytes 'wins'.

The reason for the word 'golf' is because apparently golf has a  similar scoring system.

The proposal given for a 'Mathematics golf' would be along the same lines, i.e. a problem (e.g. a calculation or derivation) is set to be solved using mathematics with answers containing peoples attempts. A similar scoring system could be used as in 'code golf' so that the shortest wins.

Comment: This could be interesting. Is the idea that the shortest way of proving/calculating whatever is asked is the "winner"? IOW, can you explain the concept a bit more verbosely to those who have never visited codegolf, or only taken an occasional peek.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have edited a response into the 'question'.

Comment: Can you objectively measure shortest solution on mathematics? For example two solutions of this form are basically the same: "A=B, which obviously implies C=D" and "A=B, and therefore (insert a proof long several lines here) C=D" are basically the same. I could imagine using some software like Coq or other [theorem prover](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/theorem-provers/info) to measure length of proofs, but I suspect not many people would want to write proofs in this way. (Certainly I would not be able to write formalized proofs in some of these programs.)

Comment: When I saw the post I thought "great idea" but then I read the details and now I fear this is too narrow. For one thing, tt seems like a subset of codegolf and it is not quite clear there is a need for a dedicated site on this. A site for mathematical puzzles and contest, including but not  restricted those you mentioned, would seem more viable to me.

Comment: @quid I agree, with our first comment, that a 'site for mathematical puzzles and contest' would be better. Although this may then be similar to 'puzzling' stack exchange.

Comment: @quid Maybe I misunderstood the post, but the part mentioning computer programs is description of codegolf. About this proposal the OP says: "problem is set to be solved using mathematics with answers containing peoples attempts". Also looking at example question, I do not think that answers are supposed to be computer programs.

Comment: @quid So, if I get it correctly, there would be mathematical questions that can be answered using a computer program and the shortest program wins. But it seems that there is already a [(math)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) tag on code-golf.

Comment: @MartinSleziak no, it was I that was careless in reading the post. Sorry! I removed the comment.

Comment: @Surb this is what I thought, but maybe the proposal is broader. Anyway I think it would be better to have it still broader.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification  AFAIK puzzling does not welcome math problems only math puzzles. And the distinction is such that  I think there is some room between [puzzling.se] and [math.se]  that could be filled.

Comment: @quid just to clarify, I don't mean that the answers should be computer programs, they can be normal mathematical expressions. (I was just giving a description of code golf when I mentioned computer programs).

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Ok, but (as already pointed by Martin Selziak) how do you measure the length of a proof? Maybe, you could explain what kind of answer you would expect to [your sample question in the proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97391/mathematics-golf/97411#97411) and what is the objective.

Comment: I think that the idea would be that the VOTERS measure the length of the answer by whatever metric they choose. I realize that in codegolf the answerer is supposed include length information, but I'm not sure that would work well here. May be number of "lines" whatever that means. I am having second thoughts about the viability of the idea actually.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think the scoring would have to work on a question by question basis. Like you said, having the voters measure is not a bad idea. For my example question (on the proposal) it could be done for example via the number of characters within the mathjax expression.

Comment: It seems to me that this proposal could serve purposes similar to what was previously discussed here: [Using Math.SE for contests](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17136/using-math-se-for-contests),
[Competitions on MSE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10708/competitions-on-mse), 
[Are small competitions allowed?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13855/are-small-competitions-allowed)

Comment: Maybe the scoring could be based on the number of calls to a given set of axioms for solving the question.

Comment: I wish a lot of fun the people who attempt to write a full proof, in detail (otherwise how do you count?), of anything nontrivial using only a set of given axioms.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi If you have a look at some theorem proved using [Mizar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizar_system#Breadth) or at the list of theorems [here](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/100/) (link taken from [this paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/200811/tx081101408p.pdf)), it seems that there are some non-trivial results with completely formalized proofs. Of course, they were checked using computers on by hand. Here on math.SE similar problems seem to be [usually in first-order logic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812949).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Note also that a whole theorem could be stated as an axiom for the purpose of the exercise.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematics puzzles are already on topic on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) and they form a large part of that site. I think that the golf part does not really work. The example questions you have so far are all on-topic on Puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Here I will sum up some of the conclusions present in the comments.

- Answers would be hard to score using any standard measure. Although it could be done on a question by question basis, or as Jyrki Lahtonen pointed out it could be done by the voters.
- Proof's and derivations seem to be out of the question, (due to the difficulty in scoring).
- As quid mentioned a site for mathematical 'puzzles and contests' would seem more viable.

Comment: Well, if "proofs and derivations are ou of the question", I don't see anymore the point of your proposal.

Comment: @Surb See here http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/23354/change-name-of-mathematics-golf-to-mathematical-contests what do you think?