# Area 51 Proposal: Mathematical Challenges

Tags: discussion, contests, area51

### **Important Update:**

> I am saddened to say that Math Challenges has been closed by the Community Moderator, Robert Cartaino (prematurely). I'd like to thank everyone who have participated in the past three months of development, especially to those who have helped suggest ideas through meta posts. Proposing is not easy!
>
> - [Unfortunately Math Challenges will not continue](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28405/unfortunately-math-challenges-will-not-continue)
>
> Surprisingly, no notice whatsoever was given. The one thing I agree with Robert is that the proposal surpasses  the intended Q&A format, but wouldn't there be a chance that this could be fixed if he posted this two months earlier?
>
> Please drop a message/answer to the meta post linked if you have any further thoughts.

---

---

It has come to my attention that there is a group of users in MSE (myself included) who want to share their own mathematical challenges.

Thus, I have made a proposal in Area 51: [Math Challenges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119894/math-challenges).

There have been previous debates on whether challenges/contests should be posted on MSE. Using [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10708/competitions-on-mse/10709#10709) and [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17136/using-math-se-for-contests/17138#17138) as examples, it can be seen that some people object, some are in favour, and some are in favour given some conditions they've proposed. I believe that this would be completely resolved if there were another site specifically for these types of posts.

Examples of such challenges are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985686/integral-contest) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812949/ended-competition-what-is-the-shortest-proof-of-exists-x-forall-y-dx), although that last one is a bit like [Math Golf](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22968/area-51-proposal-mathematics-golf).

A clear distinction between Puzzling SE and this (future) site is that the former site doesn't allow purely mathematical problems. For example, [this post of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59574/2018-january-challenge-geometry) was closed there, because "it appears to be a mathematics problem, as opposed to a mathematical puzzle."

Users who are interested in the creation, sharing and answering of mathematical challenges are more than welcome to follow the proposal. In the meantime, a bonus is that you can start thinking of challenge problems to be posted in the "example problems" section :)

*If you wish to further discuss this, feel free to use [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82675/area-51-proposal-math-challenges)*

---

**Updates from Area 51 Discussions:**

- [How will this community deal with homework type questions?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28219/how-will-this-community-deal-with-homework-type-questions) *answered + accepted*
- [What is the purpose of the cutoff date?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28227/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-cutoff-date) *answered*
- [Questions about math challenges, or general theory?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28225/questions-about-math-challenges-or-general-theory) *unanswered*
- [Are math competition problems on topic?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28223/are-math-competition-problems-on-topic) *answered*
- [How is this similar or different to Art of Problem Solving forums?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28248/how-is-this-similar-or-different-from-art-of-problem-solving-forums) *answered*
- [What to do with serial downvoting of my proposal?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28324/what-to-do-with-serial-downvoting-of-my-proposal) *answered + accepted*
- [Wording of Site Description](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28356/wording-of-site-description) *unanswered*
- [Is it on-topic to simply post a math puzzle as a question?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28358/is-it-on-topic-to-simply-post-a-math-puzzle-as-a-question) *answered*

Comment: I think it is good if and only if "original" also means "not taken from homework". But then there is already AOPS for that...

Comment: @user21820 Yes, and there are many sites that share the same purpose. IMO AoPS isn't as good as SE. What I can see is that this post will become highly controversial...

Comment: Well, I think this is a great idea! You have already received my upvote! I am [currently trying](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28218/how-must-i-follow-this-newly-created-proposal) to follow the proposal :D

Comment: Which sites have you posted this notice to, @TheSimpliFire?

Comment: @amWhy Just Math Meta, as I believe that MSE is most relevant for this.

Comment: It seems to me there that "challenging math problems" is far too broad of a problem, and varies across the spectrum of users' education.  I'd like to see this "definition" a much more objectified in a definition.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire  When did you last run this idea by someone else, besides today?

Comment: Thanks for your reply above, @TheSimpliFire

Comment: @amWhy Please take a look at [my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82585/thesimplifires-chatroom). I've already invited you. I was talking to quid this morning about it as I've just started a fortnight challenge (on my profile).

Comment: I think the idea could conceivably work (I certainly don't want to drain anyone's enthusiasm); but issues raised by John Ma, as well as finding a niche that is well defined, doesn't overlap with current puzzle sites or MSE, and is significant enough/has enough interest to warrant the birth of another SE site is going to take a lot more work than a proposal and a post on MSE.

Comment: @amWhy I understand. What would you advise me to do? Could you help make the definition more specific?

Comment: Your most recent answer troubles me.  But, I'm not going to say it's a bad idea.  I think you have a significant amount of work ahead of you.

Comment: Will it get mathjax functionality?

Comment: The SimpliFire and @amWhy: Regarding MathJax, every SE site that can make a case for it being useful can get MathJax. But this is only done once the site is actually created (and then it takes some brief period and making-a-case for it). On Area51 I think there'll be no MathJax; for the site itself I cannot imagine there being any issue getting it. Except that SE seems attached to their due process so they won't launch it with MJ but will have the site ask for it.

Comment: Please stop these incessant updates about every minor thing happening on your proposal.

Comment: If people want to come together to a) set maths challenges and b) solve maths challenges, maybe it would be good to have a place where the vigilantes that would prevent them from doing so were kept at bay.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that if I

(1) put a 400 bounty,

(2) edit the question to set up some time constraint and rule, and

(3) delete all efforts/context

to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523027/a-math-contest-problem-int-01-ln-left1-frac-ln2x4-pi2-right-frac), then they become a "mathematical challenge" question. Actually the same goes for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952466/does-there-exist-a-bijection-of-mathbbrn-with-itself-such-that-the-forward), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384902/classification-of-local-artin-commutative-rings-which-are-finite-over-an-algeb), or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661194/gradient-estimate-question-about-inequality-vs-equality-sign-in-one-part).

I don't think it works: all mathematical questions are "challenges". It seems to me that the difference between the proposal new sites and MSE is how a question is presented.

Comment: I should also add that the OP knows what the answer is. I have edited.

Comment: It's not clear in all the examples that I link the OP knows the answer or not in advance, @TheSimpliFire.

Comment: Perhaps OP should also say that after the time constraints, they will themselves put up their answer.

Comment: Regarding your edit, no. The asker *must* know the answer to their question. This is the main obstacle for such posts on MSE. I refer you to [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10708/competitions-on-mse/10709#10709).

Comment: Again, it cannot be checked, @TheSimpliFire. Even if they think they know, their answer might be wrong.

Comment: Introducing the site would resolve the issue, unless, of course, MSE allows these questions

Comment: That can't be the sole purpose, @TheSimpliFire Someone proposed "math HW" in area 51 earlier this year and got deleted since it looks like a dump site for MSE. Related post [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28259/three-levels-of-math).

Comment: As an aside, I think that a meta discussion is needed concerning those challenging integral questions on MSE, we can't just delete all of them, as those are.... challenging and generate interesting answers. A recent post [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29007/reason-of-closing-a-question-with-good-answers)

Comment: @JohnMa how about or any questions where the OP does not know the answer with $100\%$ confidence shall be closed for being too broad, perhaps, or for a better reason. And yes, "math HW" was proposed earlier this year, which is a good point because the intended "challenges" can really just be homework. Perhaps, then, there must be a certain criterion that each challenge should meet; for example, [this user](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18514/oray) makes heaps of similarly constructured math-themed puzzles.

Comment: @JohnMa regarding the integrals they could go to that new site if they are intended as a challenge and if they have an actual mathematical motivation it should be included and can stay here.

Comment: "It seems to me that the difference between the proposal new sites and MSE is how a question is presented. " How is this a problem? (Presumably over time the Challenges site would work out some constraints.)

Comment: @quid Of course, currently the proposed site and descriptions are rather broad. As time goes by I'm sure we'll be more specific as to its purpose.

Comment: @quid The problem is that IMO SE won't create a site just to generate a subset of the Q&A that MSE could provide. The new proposal look just like MSE with a different format.

Comment: @JohnMa So is MO! (with harder maths), although you can argue that it is a subsidiary of SE.

Comment: Well, quite a lot of Qs in MSE would be off-topic in MO, so there's a difference. @TheSimpliFire

Comment: BTW, @TheSimpliFire I have no idea what does [this question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119894/math-challenges/119896#119896) mean.... What are those notations?

Comment: @JohnMa they might not create it as SE seems not keen on  such "fun" sites, but PPCG also exists. The questions also only "differ in presentation" from a Q that might be asked on SO. This difference in presentation (and motivation!) changes the entire dynamic though.

Comment: I think John Ma's second to last comment is valid:  What does the question mean?  I was told by TheSimpliFire that the new site would use mathjax.  Not clear why it's not rendering.  Though that might be a step in a long process, that perhaps even Thesimplifire is not clear about.

Comment: @JohnMa re the Q on Area51, if it's not clear how about you comment there, not here. I think one can kind of see what is intended but I did not get a piece of notation either. It's about the probability of X+Y-Z being less than a when X,Y,Z follow certain prescribed distributions, Normal, Binomial, Poisson I'd suppose. But I'm not certain how the parameters are intended to be read.

Comment: @quid, it is not at all true that the questions on PPCG differ only from those on SO in presentation. There may be some small number of questions which could be reworded to fit SO, but they're the exception rather than the rule. It would be less inaccurate to say that many questions on PPCG could, *with the addition of a reference implementation*, be re-written to suit codereview.stackexchange.com (apart from the fact that CR explicitly bans requests to golf code).

Comment: @PeterTaylor possibly I was stretching the analogy a bit. The point I meant to make is though that most questions on the contest site I think **would not fit the format of this site** well or at all either. Some of the questions in OP in current form are already borderline. With the changes proposed they would create significant push-back from parts of the community. There might be a niche for this site. To say that's not needed because it's possible to do this  here anyway is a disservice to the new idea and to this site. At least that's my opinion.

Comment: An important point is that the site would contain math problems for the sake of recreation, whereas MSE (according to some big users on the side) seems to be limited to math problems for those who need help with them.

Comment: @Frpzzd I think what you say is similar to what is suggested in [this commet](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/area-51-proposal-mathematical-challenges/29044?noredirect=1#comment122718_29044). Again this is a matter of presentation. I have asked several questions here which I know the answer beforehand (or when I was half way posting my answer). Whether or not a user "really" need help cannot be observed from the post and should not be used as a criterion.

Comment: Regarding what @Frpzzd said. I agree with John Ma that the user asking needs help is not the actionable or real criterion (even I even might put it like this sometimes for brevity). However, what to me is a real criterion is that the question is a question that is not completely contrived and artificial. It should be a question that somebody might plausibly have. The site(s) is ultimately here to be useful, not to be a playground. (There is no problem with a "fun" problem here or there, but as a rule the site is for 'real' questions.)

Comment: @quid I think we (through the Area 51 Discussions) have worked something out. **1)** Non-original problems allowed but must be made CW. **2)** No HW questions. **3)** New idea: for every question, OP must prepare an answers in a *locked spoiler*, until after a certain deadline when it becomes a normal spoiler. **4)** The time constraints issue would be dealt with from the previous point. **5)** Yes, the site may be similar to MSE and AoPS, but look at PPCG: isn't that similar to SO and [CodeGolf.io](https://code-golf.io/)?

Comment: @quid Of course, for 3), we would require SE to implement this, but I suppose it won't be too difficult to do since it would work in a similar way to bounties.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thanks for the info; I am not sure about the CW thing. Maybe I'll look into it in more detail later.

Answer (score 2):

My puzzle questions in math.se are [Evaluation of a slow continued fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/368541/442) and [Evaluation of a continued fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351333/evaluation-of-a-continued-fraction) ...

If problems such as these are welcome in math.se, that is great.  But if not, perhaps we do need a "Mathematical Challenges" forum.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for following the proposal! You're also welcome to propose example questions. As much as I agree with [this post](https://tinyurl.com/y89e63jx), I find [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17136/using-math-se-for-contests?noredirect=1&lq=1) contradictory, posted 4 years later. Note that the former question is about users solving existing problems, not creating their own, which is the main purpose of the proposed site! Please take a look at [my post](https://tinyurl.com/ya7g93vf) where I received 3 downvotes, and the question was closed twice.